# If statement for if value is 2 days before Now() or 2 days after Now()

Tags: vba, excel

How could I code an `If` statement that would prompt a msgbox if a value in range `datereconcile` is within 2 days of the current date?

```
Sub upcoming_alert()

Dim qw As Variant
Dim datereconcile As Range
Dim DATEROW As Long
Dim nowpos2, nowneg2 As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook


Set datereconcile = wb.Sheets(1).Range("H:H")
DATEROW = datereconcile(datereconcile.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row   ' Get last filled cell
Set datereconcile = Range(datereconcile(1), datereconcile(DATEROW)) ' Reduce rng size

nowpos2 = Date - 2
nowneg2 = Date - 1


For Each qw In datereconcile
    If qw.Value >= nowpos2 Then
    MsgBox ("Date drop upcoming")

End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is not working in your current code?

Comment: `If Abs(qw.Value - Date) >= 2 Then`

Comment: @TimWilliams I would make sure to cast the value as a date: IF ABS(CDATE(qw.Value) - Date) >= 2 THEN

Comment: The current if statement is just a placeholder. I was not able to create in between date logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually modify your code just slightly.  I prefer to work with simple `For` loops and use integer variables rather than `For Each qw In datereconcile` (preference and quicker for me to decode).  The following macro will take all the cells in Column H (8) and go from row 1 to the *nth* row.  It will then look at the date value and compare it to today's date.  If the date is within 2 days of today, it will print the date in the Debug console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+G inside the VBA Editor).  You can replace this with your alert function if you want to.

### Edit

Added `IsDate` check to make sure there will not be an error if a string is stored rather than a date in Column H.

### Macro

```
Sub upcoming_alert()
'Dimensions all variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim daySpan As Integer
Dim Ro As Integer
Dim Co As Integer

    'the date column in numerical format (represents column H)
    Co = 8

    'Creates a reference to the parent of all child objects inside of the WITH clause
    With ThisWorkbook
        'Determines the last date in the given column
        lastRow = .Sheets(1).Cells(.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, Co).End(xlUp).Row
        'The number of days you want to "look around" from today's date
        daySpan = 2

        'Loops through all the rows in the
        For Ro = 1 To lastRow
            'Checks to make sure the given cell's value is a date and not a string
            If IsDate(CDate(.Sheets(1).Cells(Ro, Co))) Then
                'Casts the give value in the cell as a date (CDate)
                'Subtracts today's date from the current value
                'Takes the absolute value and compares it to daySpan (2 by default) as a "2 day lookaround"
                If Abs(CDate(.Sheets(1).Cells(Ro, Co)) - Date) <= daySpan Then
                    'removed the alert because I didn't want to have to hit enter a bunch of times
                    'DO SOMETHING IN HERE
                    Debug.Print .Sheets(1).Cells(Ro, Co)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: nice use of absolute value.

Comment: type mismatch on line `If Abs(CDate(.Sheets(1).Cells(Ro, Co)) - Date) >= daySpan Then`?

Comment: You have a non-date value inside of the column you are looping through.  Is your column a mix of dates and strings?

Comment: Yes, thank you, there was a header, I adjusted the beginning of the for loop. The loop works, but every cell in the column is quantifying within the 2 day span, I have dates years away from the present `date`

Comment: Check the new code...I had >= rather than <= so I was capturing everything OUTSIDE of 2 days, not WITHIN 2 days (sorry, my bad)

Comment: A lot of the data in Column H consist of duplicate values, is there a way to edit the code to remove duplicates and only return unique value within the `dayspan`?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information about how your code is structured, whether you want to remove the entire row or simply not count the occurrences greater than 1, and what are you actually changing/updating on your spreadsheet (you originally had an Alert dialog, but this doesn't seem to be a very efficient way of capturing a lot of data).

Comment: Only count the occurrences, no deleting of rows. The goal is to prompt the user with dates within 2 dayspan. There is no need to capture data, after the dayspan has passed, cutting the row at this point would be desirable and then inserting a prior month sheet (i.e. December 2014) and then adding the cut row to that sheet as an archive. The spreadsheet acts as a calendar of data point events on select days and I am looking to code notifications for each event on each day through a msgbox or perhaps another VBA feature I am not yet aware of.